# Windows App - 32 bit and 64 bit Office

Tags: c#, windows, excel

I have a C# Windows application, which uses ACEOLEDB 12 to connect to Excel. I have a mix of users:

- 32-bit OS with 32-bit Office
- 64-bit OS with 32-bit Office
- 64-bit OS with 64-bit Office

Currently the app is built with the x86 configuration which fails when targeting an Office 64-bit installation. I'd like to have a single Setup Project for all 3 scenarios above.

Is this possible or do I need to provide a 32-bit & a 64-bit version of my application?
i.e. create a Setup Project targeting an x86 build and another targeting an x64 build?

Comment: Why not just stick with your x86 app and get any clients missing ACE x86 to install it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13255)?

Comment: @CharlesMager I've only got x86 office on x64 os to hand, but I've seen in the past that you can't install any x64 Office appliction if you have any x86 Office application installed (and vice-versa) - have you tested that redistributable is installable with x64 office present?

Comment: I hadn't considered that. You can add the `/passive` switch to force it to install, I believe.  Though this may present its own issues - I'd suggest some research.  [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/abf34eea-1029-429a-b88e-4671bffcee76/why-cant-32-and-64-bit-access-database-engine-aceoledb-dataproviders-coexist) has some comments on doing this as a starter.

Comment: *Why* do you connect to Excel? If it's only to create/read Excel files, use a library like EPPlus to create real XLSX files directly, without using OLEDB. In any case. Otherwise, you have no option than to create two setup packages, either separate or using a bootstrapper to select the appropriate version. You simply can't mix libraries of different bitness, and the ACE driver cant' have different bittnes than the installed Office version